# AWS CLI | esc return text

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

How do I escape the AWS CLI return text?
i.e. go back to `~$:`

For example:

```
~$: aws s3api list-buckets
BUCKETS 2021-01-21T10:19:17+00:00       mybucket
BUCKETS 2021-05-18T11:37:38+00:00       foobarmadness
OWNER   itsbritneybitch
(END)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just press `q` to exit back to your shell.

The `q` keypress serves as a quit signal for whatever the pager the aws cli uses.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your AWS command-line tools are configured to pipe their output through a "pager" - a tool to display one page (screenful) of output at a time.

The simplest pager is called `more`, because it displays one page then waits with the prompt "--More--" for you to request the next page or exit. The more advanced tool commonly used is called `less` (cheekily documented as "the opposite of `more`"), which allows you to freely scroll up and down the output.

Both tools can be exited by pressing `q`.

You can customise the pager used by most tools, including its command-line options, by setting the environment variable `$PAGER`. For instance, if you set `PAGER='/usr/bin/less -FX'` then `less` will run in a mode that automatically exits if the output is smaller than the screen.